# Does the command-line copy command work in 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, 64-bit

I am automating a script which includes:

```
copy \\192.168.0.200\exportfiles\customersbysalesperson.csv %USERPROFILE%\Documents
```

The customer responded to me saying:

> The PCO session A command prompt screen comes up.  It says "The syntax of the command is incorrect. Press any key to return." I hit return and the screen goes blue and then returns to menu. Nothing shows up in my Docs.

I have tested in on my Windows Vista 32 bit and it works okay. I don't know what version of Windows they are running. Looking into that information now. Would this work in 64-bit versions of Windows?

PCO is PC Organizer (described briefly at [Using the Start PC Command (STRPCCMD) in Host On-Demand](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/hodhelp/v9r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.hod9.doc%2Fhelp%2Fstrpccmd.html)), it is a way to run PC commands on the user's PC from the IBM i. In my day job, we use it to automatically download CSV files that the IBM i generates so the user can just go into their personal documents location to make it easier for them. This question probably starts to flow into other SE sites, thus why I kept it so simple to begin with.

I guess it's back the drawing board as to what is happening.

Comment: This question is a bit trivial. You mention PCO. From a bit of Googling, it seems like it might be related to an IBM WebSphere software product. Can you be a bit more specific about the situation here?

Comment: I added more detail. Feel free to move the question if it no longer works on this site.

Comment: If the username (and hence %USERPROFILE%) has a space in it, that command won't work.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Make that an answer. That makes the most sense to me. I am going to try adding double quotes around it to see if that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does:

[image]

Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have anything 64-bit to try it. I seen some sites say that old DOS commands didn't work. This just proves them wrong.

Comment: I guess technically, this is the answer to my question...